# Combobox displays duplicate items when an item is selected

Tags: .net, winforms, combobox

I have a data-bound combobox on a Windows form.  When I select an item, all of the other bound components update properly.  However, the list of drop-down items changes so that the selected item is duplicated in the list.  For example, here is the original list:

[image]

This is what the list looks like when I select an item:

[image]

The combobox is bound to a bindingsource that gets its data from a LINQ to SQL query.  The Display Member is the SpecName, the Value Member is the SpecID and the Selected Value is the SpecID field in the bindingsource.

How can I correct this duplication behavior?

Comment: Please provide us with your code. This will be helpful. Especially the code that runs when item changed.

Comment: I have no code for any events for the combobox or its bindingsource.  The only code is in the form's Load event, where I populate the bindingsource: Me.NSSpecificationBindingSource.DataSource = NSDBDataAccess.NSDataConduit.GetSpecifications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I encountered a similar situation, the cause was the combobox Databindings|Text property.

I could duplicate the behavior described when this property was set to the relevant binding source and display field.

Setting the property to None caused the behavior to cease.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's similar to my problem 1 month ago,whene I  filled the `comboBox` I did'nt clear my dataset so I had duplicate data  in my `comboBox`, so I added `ds.clear()` before filling the `comboBox` in the code.