# Combobox displays duplicate items when any item is selected overwiting another item

Tags: c#, winforms

I am doing a winforms project with C# as code behind in VS 2010.

I have a combobox which is populated from a db table using tableadaptor.fill

Each time I select any value in this combobox, the selected value overwrites another existing item in the combobox and therefore appears twice. As shown below:

Here, I click combobox and select LEP 2013

[image]

Now when I click again on the combobox, LEP 2013 overwrites SFT 2013 and appears twice.

[image]

Also, there is no code written on the selection of the item in the combobox, only the Fetch button does the next action. This behavior occurs even before the Fetch button can be clicked.

Another observation is that when I select the first item in the combobox, in this case SFT 2013, it will not duplicate the item.

This question is similar to 
[Combobox displaying duplicate items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6372739/combobox-displaying-duplicate-items)
and 
[Combobox displays duplicate items when an item is selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6091239/combobox-displays-duplicate-items-when-an-item-is-selected)

But their solutions don't work for me. The column of the table that this combobox is bound to, is the primary key of that table, so it will not contain duplicate values.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

I removed the existing data binding for the combobox and rebound using a new adapter and the issue went away.

However I still don;t know what the earlier issue was. Somehow, the first item of the combobox's Text was getting replaced by the SelectedItem's text.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem except I was using a datatable to populate my combobox.  I put dataTable.Clear(); at the beginning of my procedure to clear the table and it solved the problem.  You should check your data sources to make sure they are cleared before reloading data into them.